# What is modern? A platform?

Tags: android

This might sound like a dumb question... but there is a new project around the corner our company will be developing in android and modern... what the hell is modern? I have been googling and all I see are games, but nothing really related.

Comment: It's Microsoft's new name for metro-ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They might be referring to Modern UI, the new UI for Windows 8. It looks like this:

[image]